# C - Setting a static char array with a "string"

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

a very simple question I am afraid but I have been stuck for days with this, Google gives me nothing, I even tried bing... ;o)

I am working in pure C under windows in VS2010.

I have a static char array as such...

```
static char word[5];
```

I can set each array position just fine i.e...

```
word[0] = 'f'; word[1] = 'o'; word[2] = 'o';
```

But what I cannot seem to do (at any point after declaration) is...

```
word = "foo";
```

Any help or pointers as to where I am going wrong would be very much appreciated.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Any help or *pointers*? Punny :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strncpy(word, "foo", _countof(foo));
```

If `_countof` is not defined, use `sizeof(foo) / sizeof(*foo)` instead.

Comment: Lovely jubbly, Thanks Mehrdad that worked a charm. I am a C# guy by trade and finding nothing but respect for C guys after having a delve into this world. I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @Nick: Haha sure, glad it helped. :) Yup I like C# too, but I found the need to learn C so I learned that too. C isn't that bad; C++ is another beast though!

Comment: yes I think its good to know C too, its good for learning what is going off at a lower level, I know too many developers that call very expensive operations in C# because they don't understand what that method call is doing back down at memory level.

Comment: @Nick: Absolutely. Even after you learn C, you should then learn about the CPU cache and how it works, because then you learn, for example, that if you're adding two arrays, *the order of the loops* (`i` then `j` vs `j` then `i`) can slow down your loop by like a factor of 10. :) (It's called locality of reference.)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays.

In most contexts, arrays decay to a pointer to its first element. That pointer is not modifiable though.

In

```
word = "foo";
```

the array `word` decays to a non-modifiable pointer to its first element ... and you try to modify that pointer by assigning it the address of the string literal `"foo"`

Comment: Thanks for your input pmg, I believe I understand the problem a little better thanks to this.